# Why would I use AOT compilation in Java?

Tags: java, compilation, jvm

I recently started reading about Java compilers. So far my understanding is, that optimization comes from techniques like tired compilation or code profiling. Now I read that Java 9 respectively Java 10 (Windows) provides the option of AOT compilation. Now I wonder: what use case would justify the use of AOT compilation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have better startup performance, like simple desktop app, it would be annoying for user to wait for it to load and then it still will be pretty slow until JIT kicks in. So then you can use AOT to already provide optimized code - it might not be as good as JIT, but will be much faster at startup.

Also some applications are used only for few seconds or even less - JIT will never have a chance to kick in. Like simple command line app that just sends single request and closes. Each function will be probably only executed once - so there is no reason to use JIT at all.

Also it might help to decrease binary size or allow for creation of very simple and small standalone binary. Same for memory usage - as JIT needs some memory to work.

Comment: I just thought about C1 being optimized for fast start up. But AOT would be even faster. I guess the size is a trade off. If you need a lot of libs, the file could become very large pretty fast. Thanks for answering my question!

Comment: @JP13 C1 will still kick in after a lot of operations - like 5000 invokes of method (real number is different and depends on a lot of things) so if you just want to launch app that will close in less than a second - C1 will not kick in too.